# How to create an Azure function and configure it with Azure Active Directory only by code in Localhost?

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I would like to create an Azure function and configure it with Azure Active Directory only by code in localhost as I did in the past with Auth0.

Most of the examples I found use Portal Azure to configure it:

- http://www.mattruma.com/secure-an-azure-function-app-with-azure-active-directory/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMk4sieku_Y

I imagine it s possible using only client id and tenant it from a configured AAD stored in a appsettings.json to do that.

Do you have git, sample, documentation or explanation to share to help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could read here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local

> **Important**
>
> When running locally, authentication isn't enforced for HTTP
>   endpoints. This means that all local HTTP requests are handled as
>   authLevel = "anonymous". For more information, see the HTTP binding
>   article.

So It s not possible to test authentication for Azure function in Localhost :(.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do Azure Resource Management deployments, then you can add these settings as part of an ARM Template. This [answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45278305/9035640) provides a sample template. Note that this does NOT create the app registration for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: I read your link, my concern is more how can I test the authentication in localhost?

Comment: There was a PR for the functions CLI that allowed locally testing this, but unfortunately it was never merged. Maybe open an issue on that repository and link to that PR to increase the visibility of this work. Here is the Pull request to enable that feature: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/pull/789.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I created an issue to push them to merge it :)